# Norris Presentation of Strong Markov Property and Gamblers Ruin

Tags: probability, markov-chains

In Example 1.4.3 of Norris's book on Markov Chains, the author examines the Gamblers ruin problem using the Strong Markov property and generating functions.  Here, the state space is $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, and the chain goes from $i\to i+1$ with probability $p$, and $i\to i-1$ with probability $q=1-p$.  Let
$$
H_j = \inf\{n\geq 0: X_n =j\}
$$
denote the first hitting time for value $j$, an define the generating function
$$
\phi(s) = \mathbb{E}_1(e^{H_0}) = \sum_{n<\infty} s^n \mathbb{P}_1(H_0=n)
$$
for the chain to hit 0, having started at 1.

Norris then writes:

> Suppose we start at 2. Apply the strong Markov property at $H_1$ to see that under $\mathbb{P}_2$, conditional on $H_1 < \infty$, we have $H_0 = H_1 + \tilde{H}_0$, where $\tilde{H}_0$, the time taken after $H_1$ to get to 0, is independent of $H_1$ and has the (unconditioned) distribution of $H_1$. So $$
> \begin{split}
> \mathbb{E}_2(s^{H_0}) &=\mathbb{E}_2(s^{H_1}\mid H_1<\infty )\mathbb{E}_2(s^{\tilde H_0}\mid H_1<\infty ) \\
> & = \mathbb{E}_2(s^{H_1}1_{H_1<\infty} )\mathbb{E}_2(s^{\tilde H_0}\mid H_1<\infty )\\
> & = \mathbb{E}_2(s^{H_1})^2 = \phi(s)^2
> \end{split}$$

There are a couple of points here that I'm trying to clarify, and I can't tell if it's me or if Norris is just being a bit sloppy in his presentation.

1. In his definition of the generating function, why isn't it defined conditioned on $H_0<\infty$?
2. In the first equality, how does Norris introduce the conditioning on $H_1<\infty$?
3. How does the author obtain the equality between the second and third line, where one has the indicator function and the other has the conditioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the conditioning is not really necessary if you bear in mind that for $0\le s<1$, $s^{H_1}=0$ on $\{H_1=\infty\}$:
$$
\eqalign{
\Bbb E_2(s^{H_2})
&=\Bbb E_2(s^{H_1}s^{\tilde H_0};H_1<\infty)\cr
&=\Bbb E_2(s^{H_1};H_1<\infty)\Bbb E_1(s^{H_0})\cr
&=\Bbb E_2(s^{H_1})\Bbb E_1(s^{H_0})\cr
&=\phi(s)\phi(s).\cr
}
$$